# Avoid saving of graphics in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

Starting R2014b Matlab has changed the way how variables are saved using `save` command; Matlab has also changed the way graphic handles are saved, they are saved as structures now. If you  have graphic handles in workspace Matlab takes it longer to save the `mat` file, size of mat file is large and when you load the file all the saved figures are popped-up, which is irritating to me. It also produces a warning:

```
Warning: Figure is saved in Oakley_19_PDEparameterEstimation.mat. Saving graphics handle variables can cause the creation
of very large files. To save graphics figures, use savefig.
```

I have a simple and straightforward question:

> How can I avoid saving of all graphic handles?

Please do not suggest that I can `clearvars`  figure handles before saving them.

Thanks

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38131166 for similar answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get information about the current workspace variables using [`whos`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/whos.html) and [save](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) only those variables whose class is not a graphics handle object (i.e. the class name string does not include `'matlab.graphics'` or `'matlab.ui'`):

```
varData = whos;
saveIndex = cellfun(@isempty, regexp({varData.class}, 'matlab.(graphics|ui)'));
saveVars = {varData(saveIndex).name};
save('no_handles.mat', saveVars{:});
```

Comment: I won't post my answer since it's the same approach as yours but from the error message in original question, it looks like the warning is caused from trying to save a figure handle (`'matlab.ui.Figure'`), you may want to filter out variables with `'matlab.ui'` in their class name as well.

Comment: @pkj: Reworked the solution to use `regexp` so it omits handles for figures, graphics, and uicontrols.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with MATLAB 2015a .  I have open figure windows with callbacks, but there's no visible item in my workspace which triggers `saveIndex` to be zero instead of one.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: Do you have a handle to that figure window stored as a variable? The above solution operates on existing variables, checking which are handles and omitting them. If there are no variables, `saveIndex` should be empty.

Comment: @gnovice  Ahhh,, my bad;  I found a struct with figure handles two levels down.  I'll have to write some recursive thingy to find and avoid those.

Answer (score 0):

You can select which variables you save.

Example:

```
save('data.mat', 'var_name1', 'var_name2', 'var_name3');
```

where `var_name1` etc... are the names of the variables you want to save.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but that's what I can not do, I have plenty variables and the script is ever evolving